# Visual Studio 2012 - How do I bind my solution to another Team Foundation server?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2012

I have a Visual Studio 2012 (RC) solution bound to a [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) server. However, I want to bind it to a [Team Foundation Service](http://tfspreview.com/) server instead. I don't care about preserving the history, since I've just started the project anyway. How should I go about binding the solution to the new server?

I've tried `File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control`, while connected to the Team Foundation Service TFS server, but I can only see that the action `Bind` is available to me, and this just re-binds to CodePlex. Which is strange, since Visual Studio pointed me to the `Change Source Control` dialog when I tried to add the unbound solution to the Team Foundation Service server directly.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I found out how to do this with the help of [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/PsudoKnowledgeBase/archive/2009/10/27/tips-on-connecting-to-the-new-source-control-and-moving.aspx). What I did was to, while connected to CodePlex TFS, open `File->Source Control->Advanced->Workspaces` and then double-click on my workspace item. This launched a dialog where I removed the solution's working folder.

After this I could connect to Team Foundation Service and freely let the solution be source controlled by that server.

Comment: This also worked for re-binding from one Team Project Collection to another Team Project Collection.

Comment: Yea great this worked. Just make sure the current Server is the one you want to disconnect from. I was connected to the other one and deleted the workspace... and nothing happened. I switched back to mine and then it worked. Phew :)

Comment: This dialog box has been a frustrating mess for as long as I can remember - but fortunately this works. It seems that the 'bind' feature is more of a boolean if a workspace exists - which really is how it was designed to be (so the workspace maps the local files to the server). It is just frustrating when many MS help documents tell you to 'unbind' and then 'bind' to the new location which for TFS doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

In case you moved your project under another SC and you need to bind it to this SC:

1. Unbind it in the `File->Source Control->Advanced->Change Source Control`.
2. In Solution Explorer right click the project and then `Source Control->Add Selected Projects to Source Control`.

Comment: whenever I do this is just rebinds to the original location. very frustrating