# connect a project hosted on xyz.visualstudio.com to tfs.codeplex.com

Tags: c#, visual-studio, tfs, codeplex

I have multiple projects hosted on xyz.visualstudio.com, now that I would like to publish one of the projects as open-source on tfs.codeplex.com, I find it quite cumbersome. For instance:

*on xyz.visualstudio.com I have:*

- ProjectA
- ProjectB
- ProjectC

and I would like to publish *ProjectB* on codeplex.

Codeplex requires the project to be hosted on tfs.codeplex.com. My initial guess was since both use tfs in back-end it must be straight-forward to connect a project to different servers.

I'm aware of "how to create a project on tfs.codeplex.com" and also "[how to bind to different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828554/visual-studio-2012-how-do-i-bind-my-solution-to-another-team-foundation-server)", however, none of these answer my concerns. The former one explains how to *move* from one server to another, which is not what I intend.

Comment: I am assuming that you are using TFVC (server based source control) And not Git (distributed version control) in VSO?

Comment: Yes I mean TFVC not Git.

Comment: For what you want to do Git would be best... its either that or the TFS Integration Tools and that is a world of pain...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not strait forward to copy/connect any two server based source control systems regardless of flavour.

If you use Git in VSO instead of TFVC you can easily push code changes between any other Git repos. You can easily push between Git in VSO, Git in TFS, Github, and Git in Codeplex.

I have a number of repos that I frequently push between projects in accounts in VSO, TFS, and Codeplex.